# How To Sort Specific Column Data in SSRS Tablix

Tags: sorting, visual-studio-2012, reporting-services, sql-server-2012, ssrs-2012

I am using Visual Studio 2012 for SSRS and my queries come from using Microsoft SQL Server 2012.

My question below pertains to SSRS and sorting.

In my Tablix, I currently have the Row Groups set up as Group -> Manager -> Owner -> Status Description and when it pulls the data from the data from the dataset, it pulls in fine. In the tablix, basically everything is a drilldown and each of the Row Groups (except Group) is hidden initially and can be displayed/toggled by the report item ahead of it. In the Status Description part, when it pulls in the records, it pulls them in as Active, Completed, In Process...which is fine because they are pulling in ABC Order.

But I want to show that specific column when it pulls in as Active, In Process, Completed...in the way that a specific file would go through the process. These are only 3 specific ways the data could pull it as, there are more, but these are the most common seen. How do I sort that individual column to get it in the way I mentioned above or a way that I can customize the sorting based on how I want it to be seen?

[image: I had to edit out names/info but basically it shows Group Name, then Manager Name, then Owner name, then a Status Description. The one I'm showing has Completed on top of In Process. The way I would want that sorted is the reverse In Process on top of Completed.]

Comment: Can you provide an example of how you want some sample records to be sorted/displayed? It's not entirely clear (to me at least) from your description.

Comment: Added picture as I could without giving business info. in the Status column, the end user wants to see what is being pulled in in the correct processing phase.

Comment: Above In Process should be before Completed...I just need to know how to sort this Status column, I know the fields coming in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use expressions in the sort order to get the sorting exactly as you'd like.

What you can do is use the SWITCH statement to number your output in the order you want. For example I have 3 statuses: "Complete", "On Hold" and "Word at Risk". Normally they would either sort as Ascending or Descending... but if I enter this in the Sort Order Formula I can change that:

```
    =SWITCH(
Fields!PRS_STATUS.Value = "Complete", 1, 
Fields!PRS_STATUS.Value = "Word at Risk", 2 , 
Fields!PRS_STATUS.Value = "On Hold", 3)
```

And now it orders 1,2,3 aka Complete, Work at Risk, On Hold.

You can put this switch in a larger switch statement to have multiple sort orders depending on a criteria or parameter.

Comment: So just to be clear, the switch expression above...would I right-click the particular Status Description textbox and click expression and put in there? Or would I right-click on the column underneath Row Groups, click Group Properties and then go to Sort tab and put expression in there?

Comment: The second. Go into the row group sorting option and put it there